# PostgreSQL - how can I Add separators to an undelimited date column?

Tags: string, postgresql, date, casting, delimiter

I have a date column that is of a string format. The dates appear like,

DDMMYYY or DDMYYYY
04032021   0412021

It has been a nightmare trying to split them and add '-' because they aren't all the same length. Not like a standard format of DDMMYYYY. I have also tried to split them by position. I have tried to cast it(the column) as a date.

Do you all have any suggestions for a way to get the entire column properly formatted and displaying as a date column? I need to filter on it.

Comment: Whoever is responsible for storing date values in a `varchar` column should be forced to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the month  and the year are on a fixed position relative to the *start* resp. *end* of the string.

So a trivial solution using `substring` would extract them and interpret the *rest* (padded with zeroes to the length of two) as the *month*.

```
select  
  dt,
  substring(dt,1,2) dd,
  LPAD(substring(dt,3,length(dt)-6),2,'0') mm,
  substring(dt,length(dt)-3) yyyy
from T;

dt      |dd|mm|yyyy|
--------+--+--+----+
04032021|04|03|2021|
0412021 |04|01|2021|
```

Conversion to `date` data type is a simple concatenation and a call of `to_date`

```
select  
  dt,
  to_date(
    substring(dt,1,2)|| -- dd
    LPAD(substring(dt,3,length(dt)-6),2,'0')|| -- mm
    substring(dt,length(dt)-3) -- yyyy
   ,'DDMMYYYY' ) ddt 
from T;

dt      |ddt       |
--------+----------+
04032021|2021-03-04|
0412021 |2021-01-04|
```

Comment: The first example in the question only has a 3 digit year. Btw: `substring(dt,length(dt)-3)`  can be simplified to `right(dt, 4)`